# Eu estou aprendendo python e não estou descobrindo porque o script não funciona, esse é de um tutorial no youtube alguém pode me ajudar

Tags: python

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import random

class InstagramBot:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(r"C:\Users\paulo\Desktop\geckdriver.exe")
        
    def login(self)
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com.br")  

jhonatanBot = InstagramBot('vaca','doido')
jhonatanBot.login()
```

Comment: Desculpe não olhei direito

Comment: Qual é a mensagem de erro?

Comment: File "c:\Users\paulo\Desktop\IgBot\igBot.py", line 12
    def login(self)
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Faltou dois pontos `:` após a declaração. Deve ficar assim `def login(self):`

Comment: Aumente o recuo das declarações `driver = self.driver` e `driver.get("https://www.instagram.com.br")` . Python é sensível a indentação.

Comment: obrigado vou testar nossa não sei como esqueci os dois pontos kkkkkk

Comment: Deu certo obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Algumas alterações devem ser realizadas no seu código para que ele funcione, vamos lá!

```
login(self)
driver = self.driver
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com.br")
```

Primeiro ponto a observar é que na função "login" após o fechamento de parênteses você deve adicionar ":" (dois pontos), caso contrário teremos um erro de sintaxe.
Então ficaria desta forma:

```
login(self):
```

Outro ponto a observar é identação do código na função de login. Python requer uma identação padronizada. O mau uso, acarretará na não execução, ou então, no mal funcionamento em geral do programa. Corrigindo ficaria desta forma

```
login(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com.br")
```

Deixo também uma dica. Na função login você não precisaria atribuir o "self.driver" à uma variável chamada "driver" pois, logo acima no construtor def __init __  você já o criou. A palavra reservada self serve para que você referencie o próprio objeto(instância) e basta apenas deixar o codigo desta forma:

```
login(self):
    self.driver.get("https://www.instagram.com.br")
```

E desta forma você até mesmo consegue reaproveitar "melhor" o seu driver em todas as partes do programa.